# Removing multiple spaces in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a `NSString`, this has multiple spaces, I want to trim those spaces and make a single space for e.g.@"how.....are.......you" into @"how are you".(dots are simply spaces)

I have tried with

```
NSString *trimmedString = [user_ids stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

It not seems to work. Any idea.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to accomplish this:

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"  +" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

The pattern is a space followed by one or more occurrences of space. Replace this with a single space in your string:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:user_ids options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [user_ids length]) withTemplate:@" "];
```

Comment: I have tried Madhavan, It is removing full spaces between words.

Comment: @user1587011 Is that not what you require? Are you saying that it removes spaces, but not replaces them with a single space?

Comment: NSString *trimmedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:user_ids options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [user_ids length]) withTemplate:@"  "];(given double space in template. Its working now. thanks...

Comment: Make sure `user_ids != nil`. Also if you're doing this a lot, make sure not to create `regex` every time.

Answer (score 12):

This worked when I tried it:

```
NSString *trimmedString = @"THIS      IS      A     TEST S    STRING   S D        D F ";
    while ([trimmedString rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
        trimmedString = [trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
    }
NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString);
```

Comment: I liked this answer the best

Comment: It's been a `while` since I've seen an infinite loop

Comment: It is an infinite loop. you are replacing the same string with the same  string Have you gone through with the code before posting here?

Comment: Dude it was a one character typo calm down.  Its fixed now.

Comment: YES, This elegant and perfect!

Answer (score 11):

user1587011

```
NSString *trimmedString = [user_ids stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

this string method used to remove spaces at begining and last of a string.

Try this it gives you what you want:--

```
NSString *theString = @"    Hello      this  is a   long       string!   ";

NSCharacterSet *whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];

NSArray *parts = [theString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaces];
NSArray *filteredArray = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];
theString = [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: +1 for filteredArrayUsingPredicate and componentsJoinedByString

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3** code of the selected answer

```
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "  +", options: .caseInsensitive)
let trimmedString: String? = regex?.stringByReplacingMatches(in: user_ids, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: user_ids.characters.count), withTemplate: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\s{2,}+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

user_ids = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:user_ids options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [s length]) withTemplate:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
let stringOut = stringIn.replacingOccurrences(of: " +", with: " ", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString* NSStringWithoutSpace(NSString* string)
{
    return [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Answer (score -3):

you can use:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [user_ids stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@""];
```