# Replace multiple spaces with a newline but leave single spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to manipulate an `NSString`. I want to neaten up the output. If there are multiple spaces in a row, they should be replaced with a newline.

```
NSString *myString = @"Name: Tom Smith           Old address       street name : 31 Fox Road      Dixton       0000";
```

My desired output from `NSLog()`:

```
Name: Tom Smith                  
Old address     
street name : 31 Fox Road                  
Dixton         
0000
```

Here's a bit of logic I have been working on. I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
    if (word_spacing > 1)
        insert word in new line "\n"
    else
        carry on from the same line
```

Comment: You checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608420/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-a-string

Comment: @ MrBr i have and it doesn't give me that very same desired output

Comment: this needs more info.. are u trying to display this string on a label? whats the output ur getting? and is this string hardcoded or ur getting it like this from some webservice ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collapse sequences of white space into a single character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/758212) and see also [Removing multiple spaces in NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12136970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give it a try using:

`NSArray *results = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]]`,

wich returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by characters in a given set.

Once you have that just loop through the result incrementing by 2 and you'll get the key value pairs. Then you could do some sort of trimming in the value for each key value pair using:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `NSCharacterSet` and `componentsSeparatedByString`.

**Solution :**

```
// Your string
NSString *myString = @"Name: Tom Smith           Old address       street name : 31 Fox Road      Dixton       0000";

// Seperating words which have more than 1 space with another word
NSArray *components    = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
NSString *newString    = @"";
NSString *oldString    = @"";
for (NSString *tempString in components)
{
    // Creating new string
    newString = [oldString stringByAppendingString:[tempString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

    // Avoiding new line characters or extra spaces contained in the array
    if (![oldString isEqualToString:newString])
    {
        newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        oldString = newString;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

**or**

You can use `NSRegularExpression`

```
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  {2,%d}",[myString length]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *output = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%@", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by the character you want (in your case more than one space) like this:

```
NSArray * components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @"  "];
```

Then you can print out each component followed by a newline:

```
for (NSString * component in components) {
    NSLog(@"%@\n",component);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have unpredictable  between the strings and you want to replace multiple spaces with `new line` then you should go with regex. The regex you are using will not work since it pick spaces `one or more time` but actually you want to pick `two or more times`.

I know this thread is already solved but have a look at this sample as well:

```
NSString *myString = @"Name: Tom Smith           Old address       street name : 31 Fox Road      Dixton       0000";

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\s{2,}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *arr = [regex matchesInString:myString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

arr = [[arr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *str in arr) {
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[str range] withString:@"\n"]; }

NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

Output log:

```
Name: Tom Smith
Old address
street name : 31 Fox Road
Dixton
0000
```

[Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/NnOVBTlgfE)

Comment: Regex is the right solution here, for sure, but why not just use `-[NSRegularExpression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:]`?

Comment: It is a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

//Call a method like:

```
    NSString *descriptionStr = [self stringByRemovingBlankLines:string];;
```

//Method

```
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingBlankLines : (NSString *)stringValue
{
NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue];
NSMutableString *string = NSMutableString.new;
while (!scan.isAtEnd) {
    [scan scanCharactersFromSet:NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet intoString:NULL];
    NSString *line = nil;
    [scan scanUpToCharactersFromSet:NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet intoString:&line];
    if (line) [string appendFormat:@"%@\n",line];
}
if (string.length) [string deleteCharactersInRange:(NSRange){string.length-1,1}]; // drop last '\n'
return string;
}
```