# Delete whiteSpaces in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to delete the extra white spaces in my string

for exemple

```
NSString *mystring= @"   Alex   mona   ok";
```

so after deleting the extra white spaces mastering should look like this
// deleting the first spaces, middle spaces and the last spaces

```
"Alex mona ok"
```

Comment: in that he was fixing only the front white spaces not the middle ones

Comment: Read answer 1 and the comment under it. It clearly removes whitespace in the front and trailing whitespace.

Comment: it just remove the spaces in the front and in the end I just tried it and it did not work for the middle white spaces

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136970/removing-multiple-spaces-in-nsstring

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cocoa's split method is not versatile enough to remove duplicate separators on its own, so you need to write quite a bit of code:

- Split your string into words on whitespace
- Remove empty entries created for adjacent separators
- Join the array back on a single space

Here is the same thing coded in Objective-C:

```
NSString *mystring= @"   Alex   mona   ok";
NSMutableArray *words = [[mystring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
[words removeObject:@""];
NSString *res = [words componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to remove a certain character like a space use this:

```
[mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```

If you need to remove tabs, spaces, etc. use:

```
NSArray* newstring = [mystring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString* nospacestring = [newstring componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This removes all whitespace and then joins the components of the non whitespace back together.